# In module-info.java I cannot export package that only contains non-class files. I get a compile error

Tags: java

In module-info.java I cannot export a package that only contains non-class files. I get a compile error that says that the package I'm trying to export is empty or does not exist.

But it is not empty, the package contains non-java files that are needed by my applications.

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Show us your module-info.java and the compiler error

Comment: Try using `opens` in the [resource module](https://leward.eu/load-a-resource-from-another-module-in-java-with-maven/)

Comment: Why not simply add either a class or a package-info.java (and thus a package-info.class) to that package?

Comment: @g00se Thaks! That worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by using the keyword `open` in the `module-info.java` file as follows:

```
open module jogamp.fat
{

}
```

After this I'm now able to access non-class files (or resource files) in packages that only contain non-class files.

With this solution there is no need to use the `exports` keyword, although you still can.